# Is this a promise error? Selenium-webdriver test fails to find element after submitting a successful login

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, promise

I have written the following test, using selenium-webdriver. (There is also some setup for mocha and chai, but I haven't begun that work, yet.)

My problem is that the test runs up to the point where I want it to wait for the page to load and to find an element with an ID of 'usergreeting', containing the text 'Welcome, ' + username. At that point, the test throws the error:
`Uncaught NoSuchElementError: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"usergreeting"}
Command duration or timeout: 986 milliseconds`

However, I can see (watching Firefox go through the steps) that the page has loaded and is displaying the '#usergreeting' element.

I don't know what I have done wrong, but I have obviously done SOMETHING wrong. Probably, I have not grasped the whole concept of promises. (See the section where I have written a `driver.wait()` statement.)

Thanks for your help.

```
var assert = require('assert'),
  fs = require('fs'),
  webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');

require('mocha-as-promised')();
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
chai.should();

describe('Login test', function() {
  var driver, configObj, username, pwd;
  this.timeout(6000);
  before(function(done) {
    driver = new webdriver
      .Builder()
      .usingServer('http://localhost:4444/wd/hub')
      .withCapabilities(
      {browserName: 'firefox'}
    )
      .build();
    configObj = require('../test/config.json');
    username = configObj.testuser;
    pwd = configObj.testpass;
    done();
  });

  it('User should be able to login', function(done) {
    driver.get('http://127.0.0.1:5207/Login.php');
    driver.findElement({id: 'UserNameEdit'}).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement({id: 'PasswordEdit'}).sendKeys(pwd);
    driver.findElement({id: 'LoginBtn'}).click();
    driver.wait(function() {
      return driver.findElement({id: 'usergreeting'}).innerText;
    }, 3000)
      .then(function(value) {
        assert.equal(value, 'Welcome, ' + username);
        done();
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in your wait statement, which is a polling function, it calls findElement which will return a NO_SUCH_ELEMENT error code, which in webdriverjs is also an assert that the element exists.

You need to call the driver.isElementPresent() function instead, once the element has appeared, then you can call the findElement function to get it, so try something like:

```
var locator = By.id('usergreeting');

driver.wait(function () {
    return driver.isElementPresent(locator);
}, 3000);

driver.findElement(locator).getText().then(function(txt) {
    assert.equal(txt, 'Welcome, ' + username);
});
```

Comment: Your error indicates you spelt the method incorrectly, it's isElementPresent not elementIsPresent.

Comment: Previously, I posted an error -- which turned out to be my own error.  :-O   Thanks! :)  I would vote up the answer, but I don't have enough reputation points, yet.